# Airflow. Run second task only if the first task's result is true

Tags: airflow

I have two tasks in an Airflow DAG like below.

```py
def check_condition(**kwargs):
    # do something
    return True # or return False
 
task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='condition_task',
    python_callable=check_condition,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

task2 = DummyOperator(
    task_id='following_task',
    dag=dag
)
```

What should I do to make
`task 2` invoked only when the return value of `task 1` is `True`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do :

```
task1 >> task2
```

Operators have `trigger_rule` argument which sets the condition when to run.
The default value is `all_success` thus no need to specifically mention it.
More information about trigger rules can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules)

The issue here is what do you expect the status of task1 to be when you do `return False`. Do you expect task1 to fail or success?
If you expect it to fail then you need to replace `return False` with `raise Exception()`
If you expect it to be success then you will need `task2` to pull the return value from `task1` (via Xcom) and then handle the value.
For example:

```
def following(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    pulled_value = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1')
    if bool(pulled_value) = True:
        do_something
    else
        do_something_else

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='following_task',
    python_callable=following,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I've added other tasks 'branching' and 'do_nothing'. `branching` determines which task to run while `do_nothing` literally does nothing. Everything works like a charm!